# On the definition of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

An algebra is given by a triple $(A,\mu,\nu)$ where $A$ is a vector field over $k$, and
\begin{gather*}
  \mu \colon A \otimes A \rightarrow A, \\
  \nu \colon k \rightarrow A
\end{gather*}
are such that:

$\mu$ is a linear map satisfying $\mu \circ (\mu \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \mu \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes \mu)$; which is to say that $\mu$ is associative.

The map $\nu$ satisfies $\mu \circ (\nu \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the canonical isomorphism $\gamma \colon k \otimes A \rightarrow A$; this shows that $\nu(1)$ is a unit in $A$

Can somebody explain to me how the constraint on $\nu$ is equivalent to saying that $\nu(1)$ is a unit in $A$? Thanks!

Comment: $\mu(a\otimes b)$ is identified with the algebra product $ab$. So $\mu\circ(\nu\otimes \text{id})$ takes $1\otimes a$ to $\nu(1)a$; also $\gamma(1\otimes a)=a$. Your identity states $\nu(1)a)=a$, that is $\nu(1)$ is a left identity. Don't you also want it to be a right identity?

Comment: This is also unit in the sense of behaving like an identity and not just an invertible element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $\mu \circ ( \nu \otimes \mathrm{id} )$ and $\gamma$ are linear maps from $k \otimes A$ to $A$.
These maps coincide if and only if they are equal on simple tensors, i.e. we have $\mu \circ (\eta \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \gamma$ if and only if
$$
  ( \mu \circ (\nu \otimes \mathrm{id}) )(\lambda \otimes a)
  =
  \gamma(\lambda \otimes a)
$$
for all $\lambda \in k$ and $a \in A$.
In other words, we need that
$$
  \nu(\lambda) \cdot a
  =
  \lambda a
$$
for all $\lambda \in k$ and $a \in A$.
Here we denote on the left hand side by $\cdot$ the multiplication on $A$ coming from $\mu$, and on the right hand side we have the scalar multiplication coming from the vector space structure of $A$.
By the linearity and $\nu$ and the bilinearity of the multiplication $\mu$ we can rewritte the left hand side of this required equation as
$$
  \nu(\lambda) \cdot a
  =
  \nu(\lambda 1) \cdot a
  =
  ( \lambda \nu(1) ) \cdot a
  =
  \lambda ( \nu(1) \cdot a ) \,.
$$
We can hence rewrite the above equality as
$$
  \lambda ( \nu(1) \cdot a )
  =
  \lambda a
$$
for all $\lambda \in k$ and $a \in A$.
We see that this holds for all $\lambda$, $a$ if and only if it holds for $\lambda = 1$ and all $a$.
In other words, the identity $\mu \circ (\eta \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \gamma$ holds if and only if
$$
  \nu(1) \cdot a
  =
  a
$$
for all $a \in A$.
But this condition means precisely that $\nu(1)$ is a multiplicative neutral element of $A$ with respect to $\mu$.